# Why do I have to set table width to 100.01% for it to work properly?

Tags: css, responsive-design, width, resolution, css-tables

I've got a div which has a 65% width of the body and inside of it I've got a table and I want it to have same width as the parent div. The problem is that when I set the table width to 100% it seems to be 1px narrower than the parent div on some of the screen resolutions. (For example when the browser window is maximized - table is 1px too narrow. When I resize the browser window sometimes the table width is correct but sometimes it has this 1px bug)

I managed to get rid of this bug by setting the table width to 100.01%, but this solution is quite rude and I want to know if there's any other way or any explanation why this happens.

@edit:

Here is the css of the parent div:

```
#content {
width: 65%;
min-width: 800px;
background: #666;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-top: 20px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 30px;
background: #666666; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #666666 0%, #444444 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#666666), color-stop(100%,#444444)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #666666 0%,#444444 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #666666 0%,#444444 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #666666 0%,#444444 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #666666 0%,#444444 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#666666', endColorstr='#444444',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */

-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
box-shadow:         0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

And the table:

```
#usertable {
background: rgb(34,34,34); /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(34,34,34,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222222', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
margin: 0px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}
#usertable td {
border: 2px solid #666;
padding-top: 6px;
padding-bottom: 6px;
}
#usertable tr td:first-child {
border-left: 0px;
}
#usertable tr td:last-child {
border-right: 0px;
}
```

Tried box-sizing already, didn't work

Comment: Does your div have `box-sizing: border-box`. If not that could solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome. Please provide us with some sample code, it's easier to comment or to answer if we can visualize the code.